# ProxyPassReverse not taking effect for relative path in Location

Tags: apache, tomcat

My backend Tomcat server sends a 302 redirection with a relative path.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 16:55:05 GMT
Server: Apache TomEE
Location: /StoreWeb/catalog/cotton-shirts
Content-Length: 0
```

I have this reverse proxy setup in Apache.

```
ProxyPass /catalog/ http://localhost:8080/StoreWeb/catalog/
ProxyPassReverse /catalog/ http://localhost:8080/StoreWeb/catalog/
```

But this is not having any effect on the Location header. Apache leaves it unchanged. How can I have Apache convert:

```
Location: /StoreWeb/catalog/cotton-shirts
```

To:

```
Location: /catalog/cotton-shirts
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html`

Answer (score 0):

Performing URL rewrites as part of a `ProxyPass` is a Bad Idea™. You should deploy your webapp in Tomcat under the same URL as you intend to mount it into your URL space and you will never have any of these problems.

If you *do* manage to re-write the URL in your `Location` header, I think you'll find that you then have to re-write all of the URLs in all of the pages dynamically-generated by the `StoreWeb` application. Once you fix those, you'll find that the cookies have the wrong path. And on. And on.

Just deploy your application on the same URL path and your life will be infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following configuration:

```
ProxyPass /path1 http://server2/path2
ProxyPassReverse /path1 http://server2/path2
ProxyPassReverse /path1 /path2
```

I'm not sure of that being a 'best practice', though